# Constant scope inside class method PHP

Tags: php, class, methods, scope, constants

```
class A
{

    public const a = "Constant";

    public function getConstant()
    {
        echo a; //why is this undefined the 'const a' scope should be available for this block too like get function
    }

}

const b = "Constant";

function get()
{

    echo a;//'const b' scope is available for this block
}

get();

$obj = new A();

$obj->getConstant(); //Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "a"
```

Comment: In order to access the constant `a` inside class `A` you need to use `self::a`. If you want to access the public constant outside class `A` you can use `A::a`. In order to make your constant global you'll need to define it outside any class.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is front and center [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

Answer (score 1):

```php
class A {
    
    public const a = "Constant";
    
    public function getConstant()
    {
        echo self::a;
    }
    
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php